# How to deal with this "error" instructions generated by objdump?

Tags: disassembly, elf, objdump

So basically I am using `objdump` to disassemble a binary from GNU Coreutils, on 32-bit Linux x86.

In the disassembled code, I found one "*broken*" instruction like this:

```
 804b4db:       ff 24 85 e4 09 05 08    jmp    *0x80509e4(,%eax,4)
```

It seems like a **disassemble error**?

And, by digging into the section info, I figure out that `0x80509e4` inside the `.rodata` section.

So does it mean that `0x80509e4` is a **jump table**?

Comment: What are the opcodes of this instruction ?

Comment: @perror Hello, I update my question

Comment: @perror Basically I think it should be a typical jump table instruction, am I right?

Comment: So, Igor answered, but the instruction is not broken at all. It just follow a strange syntax. When left empty, the argument is assumed to be 1 in memory addressing. And, yes, this is most likely a jump table.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

This is just the ugly AT&T syntax. In Intel syntax it's:

```
jmp dword ptr [eax*4+0x80509e4]
```

And yes, it's most likely a jump table.

You can switch `objdump` to Intel syntax by adding `-M intel` to the command line.